# C0000409 exception after compiling in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, exception, crash, visual-studio-2012

Right after moving to VS2012 from VS2010, i keep getting the same crash over and over.
A BEX error with code C0000409.

```
static void LoadBonus()
{
    // Get Bonus EXP
    {
        sql::Statement* stmt = mysql_con_sps->createStatement();
        sql::ResultSet* res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT `value` FROM `variables` WHERE `name` = 'expbonus'");

        if (res->next())
        {
            dwBonusEXP = res->getInt("value");
            delete stmt;
            delete res;
        }
        else
        {
            delete stmt;
            delete res;
            printf("MySQL Error: GetBonusEXP Failed.\n");
            WriteToFile("SQLLog.txt", "MySQL Error: GetBonusEXP Failed.\n");
            ExitProcess(0);
        }
    }

    // Get Bonus SP
    {
        sql::Statement* stmt = mysql_con_sps->createStatement();
        sql::ResultSet* res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT `value` FROM `variables` WHERE `name` = 'spbonus'");

        if (res->next())
        {
            dwBonusSP = res->getInt("value");
            delete stmt;
            delete res;
        }
        else
        {
            delete stmt;
            delete res;
            printf("MySQL Error: GetBonusSP Failed.\n");
            WriteToFile("SQLLog.txt", "MySQL Error: GetBonusSP Failed.\n");
            ExitProcess(0);
        }
    }

    printf("[Server] BonusExp: %d  BonusSP: %d\n", dwBonusEXP, dwBonusSP);
}
```

Right at the end of this function the compiler is adding a call which is related to the /GS flag, the C0000409 crash crashs in there.

Why does it happen and how can i fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: are you sure its ` instead of '

Comment: He means the backtick is wrong, it should be a single quote instead